# Check Box Condition user is enable or disable

Tags: jquery

I want check condition by check box user is enable or not. By defaut it will check means By default user will enalbe. but now if user want to update then he can click on check box, it will disable and it will reflect on the data base.

My code is below:

```
$("#btnEditOffModal").click(function () {
   $.ajax({                                        
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/DocumentLogSystem/MCRequest.aspx/UpdateIndOfficer',                        
        data: "{'UId':'" + OffId + "','FirstName':'" + $("#txtEdOffFirstName").val() + "','LastName':'" + $("#txtEDoffLastName").val() + "','Desig':'" + $("#txtEdOffDesig").val() + "','AgencyName':'" + $("#ddlEDOffAgency").val() + "','Flag':'" + $("#hdntableref").val() + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (result) {
                $("#" + OffId).closest("tr").find("td:eq(0)").html($("#ddlEDOffAgency option:selected").text());
                $("#" + OffId).closest("tr").find("td:eq(1)").html($("#txtEdOffFirstName").val());
                $("#" + OffId).closest("tr").find("td:eq(2)").html($("#txtEDoffLastName").val());
                $("#" + OffId).closest("tr").find("td:eq(3)").html($("#txtEdOffDesig").val());
                $("#hdntableref").val('');
             }
      });

  });
```

Comment: Not clear what u want to do with checkbox click ? is it ajax call not working ? can u give fiddle and tell whats not working !!

Answer (score 0):

On both my Xampp server and jsfiddle, data with double quotes: `data: {"key":"value"}` always sent an empty object to the server. Using single quotes: `data: {'key':'value'}` sent valid a json object. So here's what I came up with:

1. Make your data and associative array (map,dictionary) by giving your json data a key, and switch the way you use single and double quotes:

   ```
   data: {'json': '{"UId":"' + OffId + '","FirstName":"' + $("#txtEdOffFirstName").val() + '","LastName":"' + $("#txtEDoffLastName").val() + '","Desig":"' + $("#txtEdOffDesig").val() + '","AgencyName":"' + $("#ddlEDOffAgency").val() + '","Flag":"' + $("#hdntableref").val() + '"}',
   ```

or 2. Format the string as individual variables::

```
     data: {"UId":'"' + OffId + '"',"FirstName":'"' + $("#txtEdOffFirstName").val() + '"',"LastName":'"' + $("#txtEDoffLastName").val() + '"',"Desig":'"' + $("#txtEdOffDesig").val() + '"',"AgencyName":'"' + $("#ddlEDOffAgency").val() + '"',"Flag":'"' + $("#hdntableref").val() + '"'},
```

Here is a working [to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f8NP/47/)

If you use the first method you would reference all your json post data in C# with:

```
Request.Form["json"];
```

whereas you would have to get them individually in the second example, eg:

```
Request.Form["UId"];
Request.Form["FirstName"];
etc.
```

I hope this helps.